# Kusto query (KQL) iterate over scalar values in subquery

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

**Below is the hypothetical schema.**

```
Table : With billions of entries
Column: info 
Column: id_1
Column: data_1
Column: Uid
Column: time_interval
```

**What I am trying to query?**

I need to get a list of `Uid` from `Table` which match some criteria like

- the `time_interval` is just 5 minutes
- the `info` contains "info"
- the `id_` is equal to "Guid1"
- the `data_1` has this pattern "Something"

Also, Multiple requests can span for each uid in `Table` like

```
  Uid    time_interval   ...other_colums....
=====================
  uid1   00:00:12  
  uid1   00:00:13
  uid1   00:00:15
```

Once I get the list of Uid and store it as scalar
Say it is [uid1, uid2, uid3].
Then, I need to query `Table` again and compare each of the values in the list of scalars to find the
difference between the maximum and minimum time for each uid
Say for uid1 example above : the time difference would have: (00:00:15 - 00:00:12) milliseconds.

```
So my result for [uid1, uid2, uid3] should be:

Uid      time_diff
====     =========
uid1      2 ms
uid2      3 ms
uid3      4 ms
```

I have the following query below for this, but the subquery which uses scalar just takes last value from the scalar defined "data". Please suggest how can I make the subquery iterate over the results in "data"

**What I tried so far?**

Also I cannot combine these into one because the data is such that after putting where clauses I just get one record and there is no time interval as such to calculate the difference. Thats why I need to first get all the ids and then query for time interval.

```
let data = toscalar(Table
| where time_interval between (ago(5m)..now())
| where info has "info"
| where id_1 == "Guid1"
| where data_1 matches regex "Something"
| project pack("uid", Uid));

Table
| where time_interval between (ago(5m)..now())
| where Uid in (data["uid"])
//| summarize dt1 = max(time_interval) - min(time_interval) by Uid
| project Uid, Rid, time_interval
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if the below is what you're looking for. Note that the [in() operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/inoperator)
is limited to 1 million values, so if you have more distinct ids after the filter, you will need to use inner join between the 2 data sets ([shuffle join](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/shufflequery) might be helpful if cardinality is very high).

```
let T = datatable(time_interval:datetime, id_1:string, info:string, data_1:string) 
[
    datetime(2021-05-21 10:53:04), "Guid1", "no match", "this has something in it",
    datetime(2021-05-21 10:53:06), "Guid1", "this has info in it", "this has something in it",
    datetime(2021-05-21 10:53:09), "Guid1", "this has info in it", "this has something in it",
    datetime(2021-05-21 10:53:04), "Guid2", "this has info in it", "this has something in it",
    datetime(2021-05-21 10:53:08), "Guid2", "this has info in it", "this has something in it"
];
let ids = T
| where time_interval between (datetime(2021-05-21 10:50)..5m)
| where info has "info"
| where id_1 == "Guid1"
| where data_1 matches regex "something"
| distinct id_1;
T 
| where id_1 in (ids)
| summarize min(time_interval), max(time_interval) by id_1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like simply combining it into one query would work:

```
let Table = datatable(time_interval:datetime, id_1:string, info:string, data_1:string) 
    [datetime(2021-05-21 10:53:04), "Guid1", "this has info in it", "this has something in it",
    datetime(2021-05-21 10:53:06), "Guid1", "this has info in it", "this has something in it",
    datetime(2021-05-21 10:53:09), "Guid1", "this has info in it", "this has something in it",
    datetime(2021-05-21 10:53:04), "Guid2", "this has info in it", "this has something in it",
    datetime(2021-05-21 10:53:08), "Guid2", "this has info in it", "this has something in it"];
Table
| where time_interval between (ago(10d) .. now())
| where info has "info"
| where data_1 has "Something"
| summarize time_diff = max(time_interval) - min(time_interval) by id_1
| project id_1, time_diff
```

For example:

Comment: Actually I tried it before but this approach is not going for me because after putting this condition | where info has "info" | where data_1 has "Something", i am left with one record and there is no minimum and maximum difference anymore. Thats why I need to get the ids first and then query for time difference.

Comment: so why do you have these conditions? Can you provide sample input and expected output using datatable()?